# Json_decode gives me an string, how can I extract values from it?

Tags: php

I can't get values from my JSON DECODED STRING

This is what I have tried

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),true);
$data = TYPE --> String
```

Gives me:

```
 "[{"name":"option_page","value":"gpinator_plugin_options"}, 
  {"name":"action","value":"update"}, 
  {"name":"_wpnonce","value":"b0b29d4682"}, 
  {"name":"_wp_http_referer","value":"/wordpress/wordpress-4.9.1/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gpinator_settings_admin_page"}, 
  {"name":"gpinator_category_allowed","value":"on"}, 
  {"name":"gpinator_languages_swedish","value":"on"}]"
```

$_POST['data'] Gives me

```
"\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"option_page\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"gpinator_plugin_options\\\"} 
   ,{\\\"name\\\":\\\"action\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"update\\\"}, 
    {\\\"name\\\":\\\"_wpnonce\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"b0b29d4682\\\"}, {\\\"name\\\":\\\"_wp_http_referer\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"/wordpress/wordpress- 
  4.9.1/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gpinator_settings_admin_page\\\"},       
{\\\"name\\\":\\\"gpinator_category_allowed\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"on\\\"},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"gpinator_languages_swedish\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"on\\\"}]\""
```

No I have tried in all ways to extract the data.

If I do

```
  $obj = $data[0];
```

I only get

```
      "["
```

I run these functions

```
$josnerr = json_last_error();  result --> 0
$josnerree = json_last_error_msg(); result "No error"
```

When doing a print_r($data);

it gives me

```
 [{"name":"option_page","value":"gpinator_plugin_options"}, 
 {"name":"action","value":"update"}, 
 {"name":"_wpnonce","value":"b0b29d4682"}, 
 {"name":"_wp_http_referer","value":"/wordpress/wordpress-4.9.1/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gpinator_settings_admin_page"}, 
 {"name":"gpinator_category_allowed","value":"on"}, 
 {"name":"gpinator_languages_swedish","value":"on"}]
```

How can I access my data?

Comment: Can you give us the value of `$_POST['data']`? What does `stripslashes_deep` do?

Comment: Is it possible that your JSON was encode twice? You could try to decode it twice and check the errors then.

Comment: Added for $_POST['data']

Comment: @jh1711 Correct!!! Thanks alot!

Comment: For one thing your Json starts with `{` but ends with `}]`  Maybe you just missed that in the post? I don't know where it came from but it looks like it's been regurgitated a few to many times.  Oh and if you do `$data[1]` you will get `{` you can read a string with `[]` like its an array.  So that is just the offset...

Comment: Who is posting JSON like that?

Comment: Show the exact line of code where you are extracting the POST data and 5-10 lines that follow it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your json object is a string representation of an object. Like if you `json_encode` a structure twice you first get a json_string, then you get a json encoded string of that string. Example: Imagine you pass this to json_decode:

```
var_dump(json_decode('[{"a": "b"}, {"b": "a"}]', true)) 
// ==> 
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'a' =>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    'b' =>
    string(1) "a"
  }
}
```

While a small change like this:

```
var_dump(json_decode('"[{\"a\": \"b\"}, {\"b\": \"a\"}]"', true)) 
// ==> 
string(24) "[{"a": "b"}, {"b": "a"}]"
```

Perhaps you should look at the data before you pass it to `json_decode`? Anyways if it is so then it's the client side the problem resides.

**UPDATE**

Looking at your post data you have supplied it is indeed what I imagined. You need to fix this on the client side. If you have no choice but to fix it on your end you can doubly decode the value:

```
$strJson = json_decode('"[{\"a\": \"b\"}, {\"b\": \"a\"}]"');
$arrPayload = json_decode($strJson, true);
var_dump($arrPayload); 
// ==> 
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'a' =>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    'b' =>
    string(1) "a"
  }
}
```